# Create a numeric variable with a date format from Character date variable

Tags: sas

I have the Character date variable and I need to convert that into Numeric date Variable. My character date variable is in the format of `monyy7.` format.

Please suggest me how to convert that into numeric with the format of `monyy7`.

Answer (score 1):

The desired result can be obtained by using INPUT function:

```
data a;
input date_char $7.;
cards;
jun2015
apr1914
feb2010
;
run;

data a1;
set a;
format date monyy7.;
date = input(date_char,monyy7.);
run;
```

Answer (score -1):

you should write it like `to_number(to_char(your_date_variable,'dd'),'99')`.

and example query :

for date `select to_number(to_char(sysdate,'dd'),'99') from dual`

for month `select to_number(to_char(sysdate,'mm'),'99') from dual`

for year `select to_number(to_char(sysdate,'rrrr'),'9999') from dual`

Comment: This is SQL syntax that SAS doesn't recognise.  The way to do this in SAS is as per the answer from @G.arima